# long to wide format, but without condition

Tags: r

I have data as below

```
ID City
x  Paris
x  Madrid
y  Paris
y  Prague
y  Moscow
z  Moscow
```

I have to obtain data as below

```
ID City
x  Paris, Madrid
y  Paris, Prague, Moscow
z  Moscow
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(City ~ ID, df1, toString)
```

-output

```
# ID                  City
#1  x         Paris, Madrid
#2  y Paris, Prague, Moscow
#3  z                Moscow
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z"), City = c("Paris", 
"Madrid", "Paris", "Prague", "Moscow", "Moscow")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64543511/680068

Answer (score 1):

You can also try reshaping:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
res <- df %>% 
  mutate(var='City') %>%
  pivot_wider(values_fn = function(x) paste0(x,collapse = ', '),
                   names_from=var,values_from=City)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ID    City                 
  <chr> <chr>                
1 x     Paris, Madrid        
2 y     Paris, Prague, Moscow
3 z     Moscow
```

But **@akrun** solution is more practical and only requires one function.

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c("x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z"), City = c("Paris", 
"Madrid", "Paris", "Prague", "Moscow", "Moscow")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score -1):

Another base R option using `stack` + `tapply`

```
> with(df, rev(stack(tapply(City, ID, toString))))
  ind                values
1   x         Paris, Madrid
2   y Paris, Prague, Moscow
3   z                Moscow
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, toString), ID]
   ID                  City
1:  x         Paris, Madrid
2:  y Paris, Prague, Moscow
3:  z                Moscow
```